# Configure Subdomain on single amazon lightsail instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, subdomain, bitnami

i have successfully installed my application using this technique https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/infrastructure/lamp/administration/create-custom-application-php/
my main domain xyz.com is working fine .now i want to install wordpress in a folder and point it to subdomain blog.xyz.com .kindly guide me how to create subdomoain on amazon lightsail bitnami to point to my directory opt/bitnami/apache/htdocs/blog.
one other thing currently my subdomain blog.xyz.com is also showing root website xyz.com

Answer (score 0):

Bitnami Engineer here,

You will need to follow the same guide to deploy the WordPress application on top of your current instance. However, when configuring the vhosts files (wordpress-vhost.conf and wordpress-https-vhost.conf files), you will need to set the domain you want to use to access WordPress

```
...
    ServerAlias blog.xyz.com
...
```

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#serveralias

> Note: You can set the ServerName parameter as well.
> https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#servername